# TouchOpacity does not cover whole menu link

Tags: react-native

I just started using react-native so sorry if it's a trivial question.

I'm trying to create a sidebar with multiple links in it. The sidebar works fine but the issue is with the links themselves. Below is the jsx for the link.

```
  <TouchableOpacity style={MenuItemStyles.ItemWrapper} onPress={this.props.onPress}>
    <View style={MenuItemStyles.itemIcon}>
      <Icon
        name={this.props.iconName}
        size={this.props.size || 30}
        color={Colours.LightGrey}
        />
    </View>
    <Text style={MenuItemStyles.itemLabel}>
      {this.props.label}
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

And the style:

```
const MenuItemStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  ItemWrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 100,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  itemIcon: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 80,
  },
  itemLabel: {
    color: '#000000',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif-light',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginLeft: 5,
  }
});
```

The link contains an icon(Material style), follows by the label. The `onPress` event is registered correctly. However the click area size is very small ie `onPress` only triggers when pressing on the icon, not the label. I would assume `TouchableOpacity` covers all nested component?Can I control how wide `TouchableOpacity` cover?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a background color to ItemWrapper to see how much  of the menu item it actually covers? Seems like a CSS issue

Comment: I tried adding background color and it appears that `TouchableOpacity` does cover the entire link :|

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `<TouchableOpacity/>`component in view that has the style you are curenttly assigning on TouchableOpacity like this `<View style={MenuItemStyles.ItemWrapper}>`

and by adding `flex:1` on the `<TouchableOpacity/>` component it will inherit the size of the `<View>`

heres a working example of what I think you are trying to accomplish with the solution above implemented:

https://rnplay.org/apps/SW983Q

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, the issue turns out to be with the prop `panCloseMask` in react-native-drawer, I just figured it out.